# Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work

Tags: jenkins

I upgraded a few plugins in Jenkins, and it restarted. I get the following message:
Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work

for some reason it is not getting by this message.

I transfered Jenkins from one server to another by copying the directory to the new machine. But ever since I did that I'm running into issues like the one above.

Comment: I'm assuming the plugins you installed aren't compatible with the new Jenkins version.  Without a specific error message, all I can say is disable the newly installed plugins and see if Jenkins loads..  Jenkins also has some error logs in the root directory that you can look at to find the relevant error.  You can even paste it in here so that we have a little bit more information to go by.

Comment: Where are the error logs?

Comment: They should be in %JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.err.  See [this page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging) for an explanation of Jenkins logging.